# Maven Dependency Tree - Plus (+) vs Backslash (\)

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

What's the difference on a `mvn dependency-tree` output between a '+' and a '\'. It seems fairly arbitrary to me, but I'm sure it's not...

```
+- com.tom:artifact:pom:6.0.0:compile
|  +- com.tom:artifact2:jar:1.0.4:compile
|  \- com.tom:artifact3:jar:6.0.0:compile
|     \- (com.tom:artifact4:jar:1.0.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
```

[I've obviously removed the actual group/artifact ids...]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's only ASCII-Line-Drawing. It only appears at the bottom line (last leave) of a branch as a kind of a south-west corner.

```
+- first entry first level
|  +- 1.1 second level
|  \- 1.2 second level
+- second entry first level
\- last entry first level
```

It also clarifies that `1.2 second level` has nothing to do with `second entry first level` which otherwise mayby considered connected with the south pin of the plus.

Comment: Great - it's really obvious now... :) Thanks!